# Can't add buttons to slash commands for my discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was trying to add buttons to slash commands using discord.py interactions and app_commands elements but when I try to run this code I get this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL2Ks.png). I can't find normal examples for discord.py implementations maybe somebody can help.

Code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="hello", description="Sends a hello message with buttons", guild=croc)
async def hello(ctx):
    button1 = discord.Button(label="Hello", custom_id="hello")
    button2 = discord.Button(label="World", custom_id="world")
    action_row = discord.ActionRow(button1, button2)

    await ctx.response.send_message("Click a button!", components=[action_row])

@client.event
async def on_interaction(interaction):
    if interaction.type == discord.InteractionType.component:
        custom_id = interaction.data["custom_id"]

        if custom_id == "hello":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the Hello button!", ephemeral=True)
        elif custom_id == "world":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the World button!", ephemeral=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=croc)
    print("Loged as ", client.user)
```

Maybe there is problem with library version but i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Button),

> The user constructible and usable type to create a button is [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button) not this one.

This is not how you make a button. Making a view class:

```
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Now, after this, there are two ways to add your buttons.

```
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Hello")
    async def buttoncallback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: button: discord.ui.Button):
        pass
```

Or you can dynamically add them

```
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_buttons() # Remember to add this line to call the add_buttons() function
    def add_buttons(self):
        mybutton = discord.ui.Button(label="Hello")
        self.add_item(mybutton)

        async def buttoncallback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            pass

        mybutton.callback = buttoncallback
```

To call your button, add your ButtonView to the `view` parameter when sending your message.

```
@tree.command(name="hello", description="Sends a hello message with buttons", guild=croc)
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    view = ButtonView()
    await interaction.response.send_message("Click a button!", view=view)
```

Note: As to not confuse yourself, change `ctx` to `interaction`. `discord.ext.commands.Context` is completely different from `discord.Interaction`. The only reason `ctx` works is because your code thinks that it is `interaction` and you *did* use it *as if* it was `interaction`

References: [discord.InteractionResponse.send_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message), [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button), [discord.ui.View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View)